# ¿Cómo imprimir la n-ésima línea de un archivo?

Tags: bash, linux, shell, sed, awk

Supongamos que tengo un archivo `archivo` con muchas líneas, pero solo quiero imprimir una en concreto, digamos la número `n`.

¿Cómo puedo conseguirlo utilizando herramientas que estén en un sistema estándar Linux? La opción `head XX archivo | tail -N` me parece poco práctica.

Comment: El año pasado y este estuve trabajando con archivos bastante grandes y `head -$N | tail -1` resultó ser más rápido que sed o awk practicamente en la totalidad de los casos. una alternativa de la que dispones es la de generar una función, por ejemplo:

`f(){ head -10000 $1 | tail -1; }`

Para invocar la función, solo tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

`$ f HUGE_FILE.txt`

Que sería más práctico que teclear siempre los dos comandos. Esta función puede adaptarse para que le pases el número de línea que quieres mostrar

Comment: @rbernabe sí y no. Seguramente `awk` con `exit` es bastante más óptimo. Sería interesante hacer una comparación de tiempos : )

Comment: en una máquina virtual generé un archivo de 1 millón de líneas: `for i in $(seq 1 1000000); do echo $i >> million; done` y luego compare los resultados de `time awk 'NR==450000 {print; exit}' million` y de `time head -450000 million | tail -1`  con awk la primera línea da como resultado: real 0m0.229s con head | tail, da como resultado: real 0m0.104s Lo cual es más del doble de rápido que awk :D

Comment: @rbernabe ¡interesante! Veo que [la respuesta de Gilles](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/192/83) incluye un enlace a una comparación de tiempos en la que se confirma tu hipótesis de que `tail -n+X | head 'n 1` es la más rápida.

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6022384/1983854

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Fácil de escribir:

```
sed -n 123456p
```

Más rápido, especialmente si la línea no está cerca del final:

```
sed '123456q; d'
```

Un poco más rápido, al menos si el archivo es grande ([benchmarks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47407/cat-line-x-to-line-y-on-a-huge-file/47423#47423)):

```
tail -n +123457 | head -n 1
```

`head … | tail …` es mucho más lento porque las primeras 123465 líneas pasan por el tubo.

Answer (score 18):

Puedes hacerlo usando el comando `sed` (Stream Editor):

```
sed 'LINEAq;d' file
```

**Ejemplo:**

```
$ cat hello.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("hello, world\n")
}
```

Imprimir la primera línea:

```
$ sed '1q;d' hello.go
package main}
```

Imprimir la séptima línea:

```
$ sed '7q;d' hello.go
func main() {
```

Para mayor información sobre `sed`, puedes visitar la [documentación oficial](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) de GNU.

Answer (score 8):

Se me ocurren varias opciones.

Con `awk` podemos decir:

```
awk 'NR==n' archivo
```

y si el número está contenido en una variable `$numero`, podemos decir:

```
awk -v linea="$numero" 'NR==linea' archivo
```

Como `NR` se refiere a la línea que se está leyendo en un momento dado, solo debemos comparar su valor con el de la variable que le asignamos a través de `-v linea="n"`. Por ejemplo, `-v linea=5`.

Si resulta que el archivo es muy, muy grande siempre podemos salir una vez se haya imprimido la línea para no seguir leyéndolo innecesariamente:

```
awk 'NR==linea {print; exit}' archivo
```

---

Si preferimos usar `sed`, podemos decir:

```
sed -n 'Np' archivo
```

Y para archivos grandes:

```
sed -n 'N{p;q;}' archivo
```

Esto imprimirá la línea numero `N` y a continuación detendrá la ejecución.

Si el valor está en una variable, debemos usar dobles comillas para que el valor se expanda y `${n}` para que se entienda que el nombre de la variable es `$n` y no `$np`:

```
sed -n "${n}p" archivo
```

Comment: :-D Creo que la opción más rápid es: awk 'NR==linea {print; exit}' archivo

Comment: @luisgulo tienes toda la razón, pues deja de procesar el fichero tras encontrar la línea que importa. Para ficheros enormes es relevante este `exit`, para los de tamaño normalito no creo que sea una diferencia de tiempo demasiado perceptible.

Answer (score 6):

`head` y `pipe` con `tail` serían lentos para un archivo muy grande. Yo recomendaría  usar `sed` así:

```
sed 'NUMq;d' archivo
```

Donde `NUM`es el número de línea que quieres imprimir.

[**Fuente**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6022431)