# ¿Cómo imprimir un rango de líneas de un fichero?

Tags: shell, unix, shell-script, awk, sed

Me gustaría saber cómo imprimir por pantalla en la Shell una serie de líneas en un archivo CSV determinado.

Por ejemplo, si quiero imprimir las líneas 5 hasta la 10, ¿cómo se haría?

Por cierto! En el ejercicio no me permiten utilizar el comando `sed`, que acabo de ver que podría servir.

Comment: comentas muchas cosas, pero parece que la pregunta es solamente cómo elegir un número aleatorio entre 1 y el número de líneas de un fichero, ¿no?

Comment: Lo de imprimir un rango de líneas es otra pregunta, por lo que deberías publicarlo en otra pregunta. Te puede servir [¿Cómo imprimir la n-ésima línea de un archivo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/129/83)

Comment: También sería bueno indicar qué pasa si el número de línea que obtienes está entre los 4 últimos. ¿Se imprimen solo los últimos o se imprime también la cabecera? Es decir, si hay 10 líneas y te sale el número 8, ¿qué líneas imprimirás?

Comment: Vale perfecto, soy nuevo en StackOverflow así que estoy cogiendole el tranquillo aún. Es verdad que he planteado dos preguntas en una, pero así es como me lo pide el ejercicio entonces yo la publiqué tal cual. En cuanto a qué línea imprimiría si el número resultante está entre los 4 últimos, esto ya no lo sé, pues no lo especifica el ejercicio. Supongo que en ese caso imprimiría esas 4 líneas únicamente. Muchas gracias por sus comentarios!!

Comment: vale, puedes darle a [edit] para añadir clarificaciones, quitar las partes superficiales, etc (más info en [ask]). ¿Qué has probado exactamente y qué te falla? ¿Has probado también con el comando `shuf`?

Comment: Gracias! He reformulado la pregunta de manera que solo sea necesario un comando para imprimir líneas en un rango determinado.

Comment: ¿te piden hacerlo por código? ¿te han explicado como programar en bash o en algún lenguaje del interprete de comandos?

Comment: Me piden hacerla por código exacto.  Es una asignatura de programación en scripting en la que nos han dado varios PDF con diversos comandos pero al final luego nos tenemos que buscar la vida por nuestra cuenta. Llevo menos de un mes con esta asignatura así que soy bastante novato. En general, estoy aprendiendo a programar, tanto en bash como en otros lenguajes.

Comment: sugiero un poco de pausa: empezaste con una pregunta, luego fue otra y ahora nos añades nuevos requerimientos que invalidan las respuestas existentes. Recomiendo probar un poco y después preguntar con dudas concretas

Comment: La reformulé porque quise dejar una sola cuestión de las dos que había formulado, y como la cuestión de generar números aleatorios creo que puedo llegar a sacarla, he dejado la que no tengo idea. Con respecto a los requerimientos, disculpen, es que eso está en las pautas del principio y no pensé que podrían servir para este ejercicio en específico, hasta que he visto a gente que me ha dicho precisamente que podría utilizar o ```sed``` o ```awk```. Igualmente, le daré una vueltita y ya formularé la pregunta cuando la tenga mas clara. Saludos!!

Comment: 1) Se oye como a una pregúnta mal planteada donde el que pregunta parece no haberse esforzado más que en copiar y pegar una pregunta de un pdf, 2) Bien planteada se ve como una que tiene muchas respuestas en el sitio o en semejantes.

Comment: Por ejemplo, un poco de sencillo google fu da esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/83383/9702057

Comment: Puedes usar awk o perl.

Comment: Gracias a Cuauhtli y el link que proporcionó he conseguido hacer el ejercicio. Siento las molestias causadas ya que la pregunta la formulé dos veces y añadí restricciones que invalidaban una serie de respuestas. Soy nuevo aquí y me queda mucho por aprender. Ahora sé, además, que está stackoverflow en inglés donde hay muchas preguntas similares a las que uno puede tener. Gracias a todos por sus aportes.Saludos!

Comment: @ÁlvaroRodríguezPardo mi respuesta incluye con detalle lo que tenía esa publicación en Stack Overflow.

Comment: Tienes razón! Disculpa es que me llegaron un par de respuestas y fui respondiendo por lo que se me pasó tu respuesta. Habría terminado mucho antes si la hubiera leído. Disculpa! Y muchas gracias!!!

Comment: en tal caso, se recomienda aceptar una respuesta que solucionó tu problema. Gracias y éxito

Comment: se trata de aceptar una respuesta, que se explica en [¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/83). Básicamente, debajo de las flechas para votar cada respuesta verás una marca de ✓ que te permite aceptar

Comment: Hecho! Gracias por los aportes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres imprimir de la línea `ini` a la línea `fin` en un archivo, puedes usar Awk:

```
awk 'NR==ini, NR==fin' fichero
```

Puedes pasar parámetros, por supuesto, usando la sintaxis `-v var_awk=var_bash`:

```
awk -v ini=2 -v fin="$una_var" 'NR==ini, NR==fin' fichero
```

Es lo mismo que decir:

```
awk 'NR>=2 && NR<=4'
```

Y usa el hecho que Awk cuando una condición es cierta imprime por defecto la línea en la que esto se produce.

Para optimizar el *viaje* en el fichero, puedes salir cuando has llegado a la última línea imprimible:

```
awk 'NR==ini, NR==fin; NR==fin {exit}' file
```

---

Por ejemplo:

```
$ seq 10 | awk 'NR==2, NR==4'
2
3
4
```

---

Su equivalente en Sed es:

```
sed -n 'N,Mp;(M+1)q' fichero

sed -n 'N,Mp' fichero
```

Por ejemplo, `sed -n '1,5p;6q'` porque imprime de 1 a 5 y en la 6 sale (`q` de quit) para no seguir recorriendo el fichero.

---

Y con `head` y `tail` podemos obtener las X líneas a partir de cierta posición usando:

```
head -n X fichero | tail -n Y
```

Por ejemplo:

```
$ seq 10 | head -n 4 | tail -n 3
2
3
4
```

Comment: añadí opción con head y tail

Answer (score 0):

En bash existe `$RANDOM` que te dará un número aleatorio en cada llamada.

Suponiendo que guardas las lineas del fichero en `FILE_SIZE=$(wc -l < ./my-file.json)`

Cada llamada a `echo $(($RANDOM % $FILE_SIZE))` te dará un número random dentro del rango.

En cuanto a como mostrar un fichero empezando desde la línea `X`. La forma más fácil que conozco es usando `tail`, ejemplo:

```
tail --lines=+3 ./my-file.json
```

```
tail --lines=+$(($RANDOM % $FILE_SIZE)) ./my-file.json
```

Si lo quieres todo en una sola línea:

```
tail --lines=+$(($RANDOM % $(wc -l < ./my-file.json))) ./my-file.json
```